# Scratch-Org from Sandbox

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

Is there a way to create scratch-orgs from Sandboxes rather from production org? Basically treat a sandbox as Dev-Hub. Devs cannot have access to production
Trying to solve the problem around maintaining multiple Developer Sandboxes.
[ScratchOrgs X n] --> [UAT sandbox] ---> [Production]

Comment: You simply need to create the developer accounts on production using the free limited access license and minimal permissions  - they then do not then have "access" to production but instead purely to the "dev hub" API. See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_hub_license.htm) for detail. If you are an ISV, this is the only way to have the higher limits on scratch orgs.

Comment: we are not a ISV - how do we get the developer licenses? do they come by default in Unlimited edition?

Comment: I cannot say for sure as I work for an ISV. However, I suggest you talk to your account manager at Salesforce.